# LockerService with Lightning Components & d3 transformation issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, bug, d3

I'm experiencing issues with d3 v4.4.0 and v4.7.3 when I'm trying to redraw some chart.

There is a problem with g tag decomposition. When I try to redraw some element:

```
    rect.transition()
        .attr("transform", rectTransform)
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.oneDayTask ?
                    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y.bandwidth(), 2) /2)
                :   y.bandwidth();
        })
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return  d.oneDayTask ?
                    Math.sqrt( Math.pow(y.bandwidth(), 2) / 2)
                :   Math.max(1, (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)));
        });
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseVal' of undefined

Issue is related to this function:

```
function parseSvg(value) {
    if (value == null) return identity$2;
    if (!svgNode) svgNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    svgNode.setAttribute("transform", value);
    if (!(value = svgNode.transform.baseVal.consolidate())) return identity$2;
    value = value.matrix;
    return decompose(value.a, value.b, value.c, value.d, value.e, value.f);
}
```

> svg.transform is missing (undefined)

It seems to be an issue of LockerService or intended action?

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: As I can see at this moment none of d3 SVG transformation is available.  
Christophe Coenraets says that D3 with version 4.4 is verified to be working: [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html)  
Yes it is at least most of it. However whenever you're trying to use transfromation you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved in the Summer '17 major release.

LockerService was mistakenly excluding a number of SVG elements and their properties from being exposed. Among these were `SVGTransformList` and `SVGAnimatedTransformList`.

Also, please continue to use D3 version 4.4.0 as it is currently the most reliable to work inside Locker.

Comment: Good news. Is it in release notes?

Comment: I'll talk to the documentation folks about getting it added.